# .htaccess Mod_rewrite - I am confused

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, get

I am having trouble to get the following working:
I have my base domain: www.mydomain.com
And I want to redirect users via an .htaccess file like so:
If someone types:

> www.mydomain.com/id

Then it will redirect to:

> www.mydomain.com/directory/process?id=id

This is what I tried:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^v/([^/]*)$ /directory/process?id=$1 [L]
```

I've put it in the root directory (aka mydomain.com/)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your example is just `mydomain.com/id` but your rewrite rule matches `v/id`.  Does the `v/` belong?

Comment: I don't know, I have tried many examples. But with no luck, do you know what I need to write in order to achieve my goal?

Comment: So you want the end user to enter `mydomain.com/id` and  be rewritten to `mydomain.com/directory/process?id=xxx`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To rewrite `/id` to `/directory/process?id=xxx`, capture everything before the first `/` *if* the request is not for a real existing file.

```
RewriteEngine On
# Don't rewrite if the request is for a real file or directory
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
# ([^/]+) captures everything up to the first / in $1
RewriteRule ^([^/]+) directory/process?id=$1 [L]
```